# Azure Redis Cache for ServiceStack always increasing

Tags: azure, caching, redis, servicestack

We have a ServiceStack-based web app and API on Azure that handles Twilio traffic generating probably 10,000 web requests a day. ServiceStack is set up to use an Azure Redis cache for caching:

```
private void ConfigureCache(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => 
        new RedisManagerPool(AppSettings.GetString("RedisConnectionString")));

    container.Register(c => c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
}
```

The cache is used right now only for ServiceStack's built-in session management, but we will be caching API responses in an upcoming version.

However, for some reason it appears that ServiceStack never expires or flushes the keys. The usage on the cache has been steadily increasing, resulting in the app crashing when it hit the original 250GB limit in Azure. We quickly increased it to 1G, but now a few months later we're at 850GB and the usage graph shows a steady linear increase.

I already set the `maxmemory-policy` to `allkeys-lru`, but I'd rather not wait for the cache to get full to see how well that will work. I hesitate to simply go in and do a `flushall` on the cache. Is there some other way to ensure that keys are deleted?

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify an expiry with your Cache Entry you're saying that you don't want the keys to expire. To invalidate keys you can either specify a `TimeSpan` when setting your cache key for how long the key is valid for, e.g:

```
client.SetValue(key, value, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Or make a separate call to [ExpireEntry* APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs#L124-L125) specifying the key expiry:

```
bool ExpireEntryIn(string key, TimeSpan expireIn);
bool ExpireEntryAt(string key, DateTime expireAt);
```

#### SessionBag Expiry

SessionBag lets you add adhoc info about a User that can be inspected before/after a User has authenticated. By default cached items inside a SessionBag doesn't expire but from [v4.0.57 that's now on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you can specify keys inside a SessionBag should expire by setting:

```
this.GetPlugin<SessionFeature>().SessionBagExpiry = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
```

Comment: The thing is, I'm not explicitly using the cache. It's only used for ServiceStack's built-in session management (I presume). Nowhere in my code do I use `client.SetValue`.

Comment: Correction to the above - I do use `SessionBag`, which looks like it uses the Redis cache. Those keys do not have an expiration set, and I'm not sure how to specify that in my code.

Comment: @Josh SessionBag doesn't expire by default, I've updated the answer to show a new option added that lets you specify the Expiry of a SessionBag.

Comment: I'm finally implementing this update, but I'm running into `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` when I put `GetPlugin<SessionFeature>().SessionBagExpiry = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);` into my `AppHost` configuration. I am using a custom user session object, but that shouldn't impact it should it? Should this not be put in the `Configure` part of `AppHost`?

Comment: @Josh The ``SessionFeature` plugin is registered by `AuthFeature` plugin when when plugins are loaded which is after `Configure()` is run, so you'll need to run this after plugins are loaded by either registering an `AfterInitCallbacks` or by overriding `OnAfterInit()`.